# How to return all documents where a string occurs in the document at least N times

Tags: elasticsearch

If I wanted to return all documents that contain the term `beetlejuice`, I could use a query like

```
{
    "bool":{
        "should":[
            {
                "term":{
                    "description":"beetlejuice"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What's not clear is how to return all documents where the description field contains the string `beetlejuice` at least 3 times within it. I see `minimum_should_match`, but I think that is to be used for separate queries in a bool. How can I craft a query to match when a word occurs at least N times within the document's description field?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/modules-scripting.html) for achieving what you desired.

Basically, all you need is the [term frequency](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-advanced-scripting.html) of the desired term in the document field and you can access the value using scripts.

```
_index['FIELD']['TERM'].tf()
```

Sample Filter Script :

```
"filter" : {
    "script" : {
        "script" : "_index['description']['beetlejuice'].tf() > N",
        "params" : {
            "N" : 2
        }
    }
}
```